# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/codec/DecoderException in JBoss AS 7

Tags: http, jboss7.x, classnotfoundexception, apache-commons-codec

I am testing JBoss AS 7 prior to deployment with a .war file of an app running in a different server.

I get this error when I try to log onto the database via the app:

```
SEVERE [] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-4) java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/codec/DecoderException
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.codec.DecoderException from [Module "deployment.app.war:main" from Service Module Loader]
      at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:190)
      at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:468)
      at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:456)
      at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:398)
      at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:120)
      at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase.<init>(HttpMethodBase.java:220)
```

In some forums, they suggest adding the commons-codec jar, but I already have it in JBoss, right? (in here: `jboss-as-7.1.1.Final/modules/org/apache/commons/codec/main/commons-codec-1.4.jar`)

OSGi is not activated, frankly I have no idea to what purpose it serves, but when I try to activate it it messes with my war as it fails to deploy...

I have JDK, but no JRE if that's any help.

Comment: JBoss does have commons-codec, as you pointed out, but your app (or any of its dependencies) may be requiring a different version than the one provided by your server.

Answer (score 0):

JBoss AS 7 does not use OSGi by default for modular class loading. It uses JBoss Modules so this has nothing to do with OSGi.

What you need to do if you want to use the commons-codec provided with JBoss AS 7 is [add a dependency](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/Class+Loading+in+AS7) to your deployment.

Answer (score 0):

Modules are not visible by your artefact classes automatically. You have three possibilities:

1. Define a global module in your standalone.xml
   http://javahowto.blogspot.de/2012/09/how-to-create-global-modules-in-jboss.html
   This module will be used by all artefacts you are deploying on Jboss.
2. Put it into your war artefact, into the lib folder. You can do that with Maven.
3. Define an explicit dependency within your Manifest. https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS7/Class+Loading+in+AS7
   Section Dependencies: Manifest Entries